# From Byte[] to unixTimestamp in miliseconds

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a simple buffer like this one:

```
Byte[] buffer = new byte[] { 0x01, 0x72, 0x60, 0x77, 0x59, 0x80};
```

And I need to obtain the Date from this value (it's in Unix timeStamp miliseconds)

So I tried to converting to long and then passing to a function I found to convert from long to dateTime like so:

```
public static DateTime unixTimeStampToDateTime(long unixTimeStamp)
{
    // Unix timestamp is seconds past epoch
    DateTime  dtDateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    dtDateTime = dtDateTime.AddSeconds(unixTimeStamp).ToLocalTime();
    return dtDateTime;
}
```

I try to get the long value from the array like this:

```
    long timestamp = BitConverter.ToInt64(buffer,0);
```

But I get this error:

```
System.ArgumentException: 'Destination array is not long enough to copy all the items in the collection. Check array index and length. '
```

What am I missing here? Thanks in advance.

EDIT
the expected value out of the convertion is: 05/29/2020 14:45

Comment: It's unusual to represent an integer as *six* bytes. Is it always six bytes? What's the endianness? (Is there a specification anywhere you can point us to?)

Comment: I'd recommend [DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(Int64) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.fromunixtimemilliseconds?view=net-5.0)

Comment: @JonSkeet sadly no, the endianness I think I could handle, if anything, and according to the documentation, the expected result after transforming to dateTime should be 05/29/2020 14:45 and yes, it's always six bytes

Comment: Adding to what @jonskeet is saying... what value do you expect that buffer to be converted to? Where did those 6 bytes come from?

Comment: "according to the documentation" - which documentation? Simply knowing where these bytes are coming from is likely to make all the difference here.

Comment: Pretty close: https://dotnetfiddle.net/mi2H3P Seems to be a TimeZone issue, still ...

Comment: Does your local time happen to be +02:00? (CEST perhaps?)

Comment: That error message is really nonsense. BitConverter.ToInt64 expects _at least_ 8 bytes or more. But it probably checks this: "ArgumentException - startIndex is greater than or equal to the length of value minus 7, and is less than or equal to the length of value minus 1." and hence the cryptic message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to `Aggregate` array's items with a help of *Linq* in order to have `Int64` value:

```
  using System.Linq;

  ... 

  byte[] buffer = new byte[] { 0x01, 0x72, 0x60, 0x77, 0x59, 0x80 };

  ...

  long shift = buffer.Aggregate(0L, (s, a) => s * 256 + a);

  DateTime result = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)
    .AddMilliseconds(shift);

  Console.WriteLine($"{result:d MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss}");
```

**Outcome:**

```
  29 May 2020 12:45:33
```

As you can see, the time is `12:45`, not `14:45`, so you, probably, want to deal with `DateTimeKind.Utc` fragment. If `buffer` represents *local* time, not UTC:

```
  DateTime result = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).AddMilliseconds(shift);
```

if `buffer` represents UTC, but you want to have *local* time:

```
  DateTime result = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)
    .AddMilliseconds(shift);

  result = result.ToLocalTime();
```